# Simple logging in .NET Core app on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm just starting to put some ASP.NET Core apps on Elastic Beanstalk.  I want to do some simple logging initially just to track down some issues. I normally use Serilog, but at this point, I just need to get some info out to a log that I can view.

I see that it captures exceptions in /var/log/web.stdout.log (running on Linux).

Can I just have Serilog's File sink write to one of these files?

I will eventually implement Cloudwatch, but right now I'm looking for something simple.

Comment: If you use Elastic Beanstalk then you should write to stdout and let Elastic Beanstalk manage the logs

Answer (score 0):

You can't write direct into `/var/log/web.stdout.log` as the file is owned by `root`, and your app executes under `webapp` user. You will get access denied if you try to modify the log file directly.

But you can tell EB which log files, specific to your application, to include in its bundles. This is done through `.ebextensions`. Specifically, you can have a config file `.ebextensions/mylogfiles.config` with the exemplary content of:

```
files: 
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle/mylogfiles.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       /var/app/current/logs/*.log
```

where `/var/app/current/log/*.log` would need to be adjusted to how your application store its logs.

Comment: Thanks - where do I create .ebextensions? Is it in the root of my app?

Comment: @JoeD No problem. Yes, more details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html).